# Inexplicably Phenome on MySQL: REPLACE INTO with strange shortening

Tags: mysql, sql

May be some of you can give me an explanation to understand the following for me unexplained effect:

When I grab PREPAYMENT values from a Table (saved as a type: DOUBLE),  for example -980.20 and replace it into a differnt table (type is DECIMAL(10,2)) the value is placed as expected (-980.20) so far the value is not lesser then -999.99 but when the value is lesser then -999.99 is placed as shortening value (for example -4233.85 >>> as -4, -2108.55 >>> as -2)

The original Query is:

```sql
REPLACE INTO `ra_fd` (`Rposid`, `Nr`, `Room`, `Name`, `Receipt`, `InvoiceID`, `InvoiceArt`, `Done`, `Form_of_paymentID`, `DoneAt`, `Tax`, `Canceled`, `Stay`, `AccountType`, `SKN`, `BillingGrp`, `GROSS0%`, `GROSS7%`, `GROSS19%`, `Cash`, `Voucher`, `Cashless`, `Credit`, `ADV_PAY0%`, `Advance_payment`, `Checked*`)
SELECT gip.`InvoicePositionID` AS Rposid,
       1 AS `Nr`,
       gob.`Roomnumber` AS Room,
       CONCAT (gp.`Surname`,', ',gp.`Prename`) AS Name,
       CONCAT(`Invoicenumber`,' | ',gi.`BookingID`) AS `Receipt`,
       gip.`InvoiceID`,
       `InvoiceArt`,
       `Done`,
       `Form_of_paymentID`,
       `DoneAt`,
       gip.`Tax`,
       `Canceled`,
       DATEDIFF(`DateTo`,`DateFrom`) AS `Stay`,
       gip.`AccountType` AS `AccountType`,
       gip.`SKN` AS `SKN`,
       "Advance_payment" AS `BillingGrp`,
       FORMAT(0,2) AS `GROSS0%`,
       FORMAT(0,2) AS `GROSS7%`,
       FORMAT(0,2) AS `GROSS19%`,
       IF(gi.`Form_of_paymentID` IN (2), IFNULL(IF(gip.`AccountType`= 2,FORMAT((((gip.`Price`)*(100+gip.`Discount`)/100*(100+gip.`Tax`)/100)* DATEDIFF(`DateTo`,`DateFrom`) * gip.`Amount`),2),FORMAT((((gip.`Price`)*(100+gip.`Discount`)/100*(100+gip.`Tax`)/100) * gip.`Amount`),2)),FORMAT(0,2)),FORMAT(0,2)) AS `Cash`,
       IF(gi.`Form_of_paymentID` IN (11),IFNULL(IF(gip.`AccountType`=2,FORMAT((((gip.`Price`)*(100+gip.`Discount`)/100*(100+gip.`Tax`)/100)* DATEDIFF(`DateTo`,`DateFrom`) * gip.`Amount`),2),FORMAT((((gip.`Price`)*(100+gip.`Discount`)/100*(100+gip.`Tax`)/100) * gip.`Amount`),2)),FORMAT(0,2)),FORMAT(0,2)) AS `Voucher`,
       IF(gi.`Form_of_paymentID` IN (5,6,8),IFNULL(IF(gip.`AccountType`= 2,FORMAT((((gip.`Price`)*(100+gip.`Discount`)/100*(100+gip.`Tax`)/100)* DATEDIFF(`DateTo`,`DateFrom`) * gip.`Amount`),2),FORMAT((((gip.`Price`)*(100+gip.`Discount`)/100*(100+gip.`Tax`)/100) * gip.`Amount`),2)),FORMAT(0,2)),FORMAT(0,2)) AS `Cashless`,
       IF(gi.`Form_of_paymentID` IN (9),IFNULL(IF(gip.`AccountType`= 2,FORMAT((((gip.`Price`)*(100+gip.`Discount`)/100*(100+gip.`Tax`)/100)* DATEDIFF(`DateTo`,`DateFrom`) * gip.`Amount`),2),FORMAT((((gip.`Price`)*(100+gip.`Discount`)/100*(100+gip.`Tax`)/100) * gip.`Amount`),2)),FORMAT(0,2)),FORMAT(0,2)) AS `Credit`,
       IF(gip.`SKN` = 'AP',IFNULL(IF(gip.`AccountType`= 2,FORMAT((((gip.`Price`)*(100+gip.`Discount`)/100*(100+gip.`Tax`)/100)* DATEDIFF(`DateTo`,`DateFrom`) * gip.`Amount`),2),FORMAT((((gip.`Price`)*(100+gip.`Discount`)/100*(100+gip.`Tax`)/100) * gip.`Amount`),2)),FORMAT(0,2)),FORMAT(0,2)) AS `ADV_PAY0%`,
       1 AS `Advance_payment`,
       0 AS `Checked*`
FROM `gv_invoicees` gi
INNER JOIN gv_invoicepositions gip ON gi.`InvoiceID` = gip.`InvoiceID`
AND gip.`SKN` = 'AP'
LEFT JOIN gv_persons gp ON gi.`PersonsID` = gp.`AdressID`
LEFT JOIN gv_bookings gbob ON gi.`BookingID` = gbob.`BookingID`
LEFT JOIN gv_objects gob ON gbob.`ObjektID` = gob.`ObjektID`
WHERE `InvoiceType`= 3
  AND `Done`= 1
  AND `Canceled`= 0
  AND (DATE(`DoneAt`) >= '2015-01-01')
GROUP BY gip.`InvoicePositionID`
ORDER BY gi.`InvoiceID`;
```

**Thank you for your interest**

Comment: Could you try to provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Currently provided query seems to have a lot of boilerplate lines that don't help understanding your issue. Also, maybe you could try to provide a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so that we can replicate?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6So8dxXLgc7tAERBiL96NU/0).

Comment: Your db-fiddle has brought me to an idea. I tried the following and changed some FORMAT statements. Now it works as expected ... See my answer *** Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me:**

*instead of this part:*

```
    IF(gi.`Form_of_paymentID` IN (9),IFNULL(IF(gip.`AccountType`= 2,FORMAT((((gip.`Price`)*(100+gip.`Discount`)/100*(100+gip.`Tax`)/100)* DATEDIFF(`DateTo`,`DateFrom`) * gip.`Amount`),2),FORMAT((((gip.`Price`)*(100+gip.`Discount`)/100*(100+gip.`Tax`)/100) * gip.`Amount`),2)),FORMAT(0,2)),FORMAT(0,2))  AS `Credit`,
```

*my new Query looks like this:*

```
    IF(gi.`Form_of_paymentID` IN (9),IFNULL(IF(gip.`AccountType`= 2,(((gip.`Price`)*(100+gip.`Discount`)/100*(100+gip.`Tax`)/100)* DATEDIFF(`DateTo`,`DateFrom`) * gip.`Amount`),(((gip.`Price`)*(100+gip.`Discount`)/100*(100+gip.`Tax`)/100) * gip.`Amount`)),FORMAT(0,2)),FORMAT(0,2))  AS `Credit`,
```

it seems to be avoiding the 1st FORMAT is the solution.

*Comments are welcome*